# How to check ACL of the each object in stored in S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How to check Access Control List (ACL) of the each object in stored in S3 bucket of Amazon Web Services via AWS SDK for .Net?

It is not only for .Net SDK, it is applicable for all AWS SDK like Node and Java SDK too.

In the below code snippet, I could not find the Access level property of each object. If the access level permission is known already, I can inform user early before accessing objects for read/write/download operations.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string bucketName = "mytestbucket1234"; //Testing purpose only, not a real bucket
        using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client())
        {
            ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request() { BucketName = bucketName };
            var bucketItem = s3client.ListObjectsV2(request);
            foreach (var x in bucketItem.S3Objects)
            {
                //need to access Access Level List Permission here, property is not available 
                Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(x.ETag); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer is to use some code.  Please post your code that does not work so we can assist you.

Comment: See the [.Net API for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/NS3.html). For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added code snippet as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't currently possible. You have two options:-

1. Retrieve all the objects (up to a 1000) using `ListObjectsV2` and then call `GetACL` with the combination of `BucketName` and `Key`:-

   ```
   private static void ListACLs(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint, string bucketName)
   {
       using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, regionEndpoint))
       {
           var s3Objects = client.ListObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request
           {
               BucketName = bucketName
           }).S3Objects;

           foreach (var s3Object in s3Objects)
           {
               var getAclRequest = new GetACLRequest
               {
                   BucketName = bucketName,
                   Key = s3Object.Key
               };

               var grants = client.GetACL(getAclRequest).AccessControlList.Grants;

               foreach (var s3Grant in grants)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(s3Grant.Permission);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or if you already know the combination of `BucketName` and `Key` then you can skip the `ListObjectsV2` call and just do a `GetACL` call:-

   ```
   private static void ListACLs(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint, string bucketName, string key)
   {
       using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, regionEndpoint))
       {
           var getAclRequest = new GetACLRequest
           {
               BucketName = bucketName,
               Key = key
           };

           var grants = client.GetACL(getAclRequest).AccessControlList.Grants;

           foreach (var s3Grant in grants)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(s3Grant.Permission);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Personally, I think if you are testing each objects ACL before retrieval then your model needs looking at. By default when you upload an object to S3 it is private. Also, when you try to retrieve a private object without the correct credentials S3 will return HTTP Status 403 and a Access Denied message. I would investigate using that mechanism if you really need that feature.

Hope that helps!