# List S3 objects with public read permissions (in private bucket)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to secure files located in S3 buckets, and ensure that no sensitive files are being shared.

I am aware of various ways (in the console and using scripts) to view which buckets have public permissions.

However, objects can be granted anonymous read permissions even when they are in a private bucket.

It can be hard to track/audit files/objects which are publicly readable because I cannot see any way to find them other than browsing through every single path in the AWS console.

Is there a way to list all the objects which have anonymous (read) permissions in a bucket? Any method would be fine, including AWSCLI, Boto, REST etc.

I considered trying to use an anonymous AWSCLI profile but this would not allow listing bucket contents so it could only be used to test files individually.

I suppose I could create a script using Boto (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectacl). Is that the only way, or is there an official method such as an AWSCLI command?

Comment: Side-note: If you are concerned about files 'leaking' this way, you can add a **Bucket Policy** that denies `GetObject` where it is not being requested by a user in your AWS account. This would override per-object permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is Object ACLs. In the spirit of [job-to-be-done](https://jtbd.info/2-what-is-jobs-to-be-done-jtbd-796b82081cca), I want to point out that you can [configure a bucket to deny public object ACLs.](https://www.capitalone.io/docs/usecases/s3denypublicobjectacls.html) This is probably among the best enterprise practices for prevention. Among the best enterprise practices for [auditing and verifying continuously is described here.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-remediate-unintended-permissions-in-amazon-s3-object-acls-with-cloudwatch-events/)

**Update**: If you're interested in monitoring & auditing *bucket-level ACLs*, [take a look at this managed AWS Config solution.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-config-to-monitor-for-and-respond-to-amazon-s3-buckets-allowing-public-access/)

However, if you're looking for a bash script/tool using the `aws-cli` (which is the tag for this question), this will do the trick:

```
bucket="my-bucket-name"
search_term="AllUsers"

for key in $(aws s3 ls --recursive s3://$bucket/ | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'); do
    acl=$(aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket $bucket --key $key) &&
    result_found=$(echo $acl | grep -q $search_term) &&
    if $result_found; then
        echo $key;
        echo $acl;
    fi;
done
```

*Here's what it does:*

1. Recursively list all objects in your bucket
2. Iterate through those object keys
3. Ask S3 what the ACL for that object is
4. If that ACL contains the string "AllUsers" (the global s3 permission group), it will echo that ACL to stdout.

I generalized this problem to "echo all keys and their ACLs within a bucket iff that ACL contains a given `$search_term`", so if others are stumbling across a similar, but subtly different problem, this solution will still be helpful, insofar as they change the `$search_term` to something that suits their problem.

**Ideally (assuming you want no public objects) if you run this... nothing should show up.**

**Keep in mind, this solution won't scale well for massive buckets with tons and tons of objects.**

Comment: Very helpful! 1 important thing to add to this script is IFS=$'\n' at the beginning of the file so it will also support objects with spaces in their names

Comment: Replace `--key $key` by `--key=$key` to support filenames with leading dashes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a multi-threaded solution in Ruby:

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org' do
  gem 'aws-sdk'
  gem 'thread'
end
```

```
# find_public_s3_objects.rb
require 'aws-sdk-s3'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'
require 'thread/pool'

BUCKET = ARGV[0] or raise("expected bucket")

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1')

count = 0
pool = Thread.pool 8
mutex = Mutex.new
s3.bucket(BUCKET).objects.each do |object|
  pool.process do
    grants = object.acl.grants
    mutex.synchronize do
      count += 1
      if count % 100 == 0
        $stderr.write "#{count}..."
      end
    end
    if grants.map { |x| x.grantee.uri }.any? { |x| x =~ /AllUsers/ }
      mutex.synchronize do
        puts object.key
      end
    end
  end
end

pool.shutdown
```

Then you run it like this:

```
bundle exec ruby find_public_s3_objects.rb my-bucket-name
```

It's much faster than the Bash-based solution provided above.

Originally from [Faraday's blog](https://blog.faraday.io/finding-public-s3-objects/).

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution described in the following post(using C#) to get ACLs for each object stored in S3.

[How to check ACL of the each object in stored in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182962/how-to-check-acl-of-the-each-object-in-stored-in-s3)