# How to display, if file is publicly accessible using s3 command?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I tried the following command to display all files that exist in my S3 bucket:
`aws s3 ls -a s3://project-files`

output I got is:

```
2021-06-21 19:18:27     184163 1624283306646-Plastic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:25:29     184163 1624283728863-water_toxic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:26:21     184163 1624283780648-water_toxic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:38:17     184163 1624284496754-plastic_solution.pdf
```

But here it doesn't intimate anything about which files are publicly accessible.
I need to see something like the below:

```
2021-06-21 19:18:27     184163 PUBLIC 1624283306646-Plastic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:25:29     184163 Can be made Public 1624283728863-water_toxic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:26:21     184163 PUBLIC 1624283780648-water_toxic_challenge.pdf
2021-06-21 19:38:17     184163 Can be made Public 1624284496754-plastic_solution.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects can be publicly accessible in two ways:

- The object itself could have an Access Control List (ACL) setting of `public`, *or*
- The bucket could have a **Bucket Policy** that permits public access to the bucket, or part of the bucket

There is **no single API call that can list objects *and* determine whether they have a public ACL**. A separate call is required to retrieve the permissions of each object to determine whether they are public.

Similarly, there is **no API call that can list objects in a bucket and determine whether the Bucket Policy makes them public**. The logic within the Bucket Policy would need to be parsed to determine which parts of a bucket are public. This can be further complicated by additional rules in a Bucket Policy that might, for example, only make an object publicly accessible from a given IP address.

If you wish to **specifically block public access**, then you can activate [Block S3 Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) on a bucket, which can disable public access granted via a Bucket Policy or via object-level ACLs.

See also: [List S3 objects with public read permissions (in private bucket) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152035/list-s3-objects-with-public-read-permissions-in-private-bucket)